# How to use Booleans with Delphi XE2 dbExpress and Firebird 2.5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird, dbexpress, firebird2.5

Does the new XE2 dbExpress still have problems using Boolean fields?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a domain

```
CREATE DOMAIN BOOL AS
SMALLINT
DEFAULT 0
CHECK (value in (0,1) or value is null);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Firebird doesn't have BOOLEAN types.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Char(1) field. Set values "Y" or "N"

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq12/

Comment: **Y**=Yes(Checked), **N**=No(Unchecked)

Comment: excuse me for poor english